# Kudan and Unity3D : Unstable 3D model in Markerless Mode

Tags: android, ios, unity-game-engine, kudan

I am using Kudan Unity plugin. I have included my own 3D models with marker less mode along with the default touch controls provided (for rotate, pinch etc.). The app works both on iOS and Android. However, I am having an issue with the stability of 3D model in marker less mode. When a 3D model is added in marker less mode it moves bit (not drastically, but doesn't stay stable). Further, when I rotate the device (iPad or Android) around, so the model is not on display, it is lost when I rotate the device back to see the model. I have seen a demo in which the tracking is stable in the marker less mode, even when the device is rotated (the 3D model is still stable). I am using the free version of Kudan. So, is there anything that I can do to make the 3D models stable in the marker less mode? Thanks!

Comment: To make the model more stable, you can do things like move more slowly, find a more feature-rich environment to track (flat tables aren't that great) or initialise your app in landscape rather than portrait mode. As for still being able to track it when you turn around, that's not how the tracking works, so there's nothing you can do about that.

Comment: @DisturbedNeo Thanks. I deployed the app with only landscape mode enable and did tracking in an environment with more features (in my case it was different object around e.g chairs, books etc). This did help with the stability of the model as compared to previous version. Thanks.